# How to check Table exist in access database or not?

Tags: ms-access, vb6

How to check table exist or not?

USING VB 6.0 AND ACCESS 2003

My code.

```
Cn.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source=" & App.Path & "\iTDC-ACS.MDB"
Cn.Open

cmdCardEvent.ActiveConnection = Cn
cmd.ActiveConnection = Cn

cmdcardevent1.ActiveConnection = Cn
cmd.ActiveConnection = Cn

cmd.CommandText = "DROP TABLE tmp_cardevent"
cmd.Execute

cmd.CommandText = "drop table tmp_MOI"
cmd.Execute
```

Here I want to check whether table exist then drop table the else no need.

How to check table exist or not?

Need VB 6 code Help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put the function below this one into a public module.

Example code to call the function:

```
Dim result as boolean
result = IsExistingTable("c:\myFolder\myDatabase.mdb","myTableName")
If result Then
   'Do something
Else
   'Do something else.
Endif
```

Function

```
Public Function IsExistingTable( _
  ByVal Database As String, _
  ByVal TableName As String _
) As Boolean

Dim ConnectString As String
Dim ADOXConnection As Object
Dim ADODBConnection As Object
Dim Table As Variant

ConnectString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;data source=" & Database
Set ADOXConnection = CreateObject("ADOX.Catalog")
Set ADODBConnection = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
ADODBConnection.Open ConnectString
ADOXConnection.ActiveConnection = ADODBConnection
For Each Table In ADOXConnection.Tables
  If LCase(Table.Name) = LCase(TableName) Then
     IsExistingTable = True
     Exit For
  End If
Next
ADODBConnection.Close

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `On Error Resume Next` as given below example. There if a table (temp) is exist in database then it drops otherwise it leave the error and goes to next instruction's without giving any error.

```
On Error Resume Next
cmd.ActiveConnection = cn
cmd.CommandText = "drop table temp"
cmd.Execute , , adCmdText
```